# Exclude everything between quotes

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I've worked with regex for super simple stuff.

Now I came up with a situation that my knowledge isn't sufficient.

I need to get this info out of a lot of lines.

Everything **after** the **first** quotes and **before** the `@` sign is what I need to have to copy to a new file.

```
0: "mailname@…"
6: "mailname2@yahoo.com"
```

etc..

I first did the following

```
(?<=")\S\D[^"]+(?=")
```

But this takes everything in between the quotes. But it should exclude everything out of the quotes and just give me the mail address or the name before the @ sign.

This is what I have so far before the mail and I'm stuck to remove the @ and everything behind it.

```
(\d{0,2})([:])\s(["(.+)"$])
```

Comment: Is looks like a well-defined format that you're trying to process. It may make more sense to use existing code that parses this data format, rather than attacking it with regexes.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure if I answer it correctly, because it is so simple, but if your write `(?<=\")\S\D[^\"]+(?=\@)` instead of `(?<=")\S\D[^"]+(?=")` you will get `mailname` in your example. And I think that is what you want.

Comment: @AndyLester If I could I would. But that's not the case. So I have to painstakingly do it this way.

Comment: @mosc9575 When testing this with regex101 or VScode it gives no working result. 
Or better it doesn't change anything? Strange though..

Comment: Please check [this](https://regex101.com/r/p3Q5qY/1) out.

Comment: This is rather vague - are you replacing? Or just matching? If replacing, try `^[^"]*"([^"@]*)@.*` (or, `^[^\n"]*"([^\n"@]*)@.*`) and replace with `$1`. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IfrE2g/1).

Comment: @QuintenDeWilde Sorry a lit bit sidetracking.  Seen you mentioned testing regex in VScode.  Could you tell me which extension in VScode you are using ?  Do you know of any good regex extension for Python for VScode ?  Anyone else know of it could kindly please share too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, take a copy of your file, then use this in notepad++

Find what: `^.*"(.+)@.+`

Replace with: `$1`

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm running on Mac and using VScode. 
But I also test everything on regex101.com and the example doesn't work on it.

Comment: This will work `\d+:\s"|@.*`  and replaced with `nothing`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find and match the parts, you could use

```
(?<=")[^"\s@]+(?=@[^\s"]+")
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=")` Positive lookbehind to assert `"` to the left
- `[^"\s@]+` Match 1+ occurrences of any char except `"` a whitespace char or `@`
- `(?=@[^\s"]+")` Positive lookahead to assert 1+ times any char except `"` a whitspace char or `"` followed by a `"` at the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Rj4hb8/1)

If using a quantifier in the lookbehind is supported, a bit more precise match asserting from the start of the string taking the digit and the colon into account:

```
(?<=^\d+:\s")[^"\s@]+(?=@[^\s"]+"$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kirlTf/1)